# FrameLayout Contains TabLayout

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-tabs, android-framelayout

I need some help.
I'm using the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstraw"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pttStatusBarIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="branding_app_title" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="branding_app_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        <--------------------------<<-  Here were i change the height
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- ************************************************************************************** -->
    <TabHost
             android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">

            <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView4"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:gravity="bottom|right" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:gravity="bottom|left" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- ***************************************************************************************** -->
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When using wrap_content in the marked place (with the long arrow) the buttons can be seen.
[image: wrap_content]

when using match_parent in the same place, the buttons disappeared.
[image: match_parent]

How can i keep the buttons on screen while tabs are displayed on the whole screen?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstraw"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pttStatusBarIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="branding_app_title" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="branding_app_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <!--LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" -->
    <!-- ************************************************************************************** -->
    <TabHost
             android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">

            <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

                <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView4"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:divider="#BFBFBF"
                        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:gravity="bottom|right" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:gravity="bottom|left" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- ***************************************************************************************** -->
    <!--/LinearLayout-->
</FrameLayout>
```

and here is the result:
[image: Fixed Layout]

Thanks anyway...